# Shuffle works weird

Tags: flutter, dart

Shuffle works very strange in dart

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = array1;

array2.shuffle();

print("array1: $array1");
print("array2: $array2");
```

and such a conclusion

```
array1: [3, 5, 1, 4, 2]
array2: [3, 5, 1, 4, 2]
```

Swift works fine. Please, tell me why and how to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing the same list with `array1` and `array2`, so you need to explicitly specify that `array2` is a distinct array from `array1` like so:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = [...array1];

array2.shuffle();

print("array1: $array1");
print("array2: $array2");
```

Comment: Decided so 
'var array2 = [] + array1;' 
Thanks for the tip

Comment: An alternative way is to do `var array2 = array1.toList();`. I would think it's more efficient but I'm not sure.